# How to get last three months in year-mon format in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to get last three months from todays date in year-mon format. For example if todays date is `2021-08-04` then I want list of last three months as -
`["2021-05", "2021-06", "2021-07"]`
I have no idea how to start with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the `datetime` module. `datetime.datetime.today()` will give you today's date. `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')` will give you today's date in the format `'2021-08'`. You can subtract `datetime.timedelta(days=30)`  from today to get the date a month back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use dateutil's [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#relativedelta-examples) to get consistent results, as not all months have equal number of days. E.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

NOW = datetime.now()             # reference date
delta = relativedelta(months=-1) # delta in time 
n = 3                            # how many steps

fmt = lambda dt: dt.strftime("%Y-%m") # formatter; datetime object to string

l = sorted((fmt(NOW+delta*i) for i in range(1, n+1)))
# l
# ['2021-05', '2021-06', '2021-07']
```